# EFCore: Insert and edit records with composite keys on a PKeyless table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor

I am trying to make a Blazor server to connect old databases for my org.

However, EFCore seems not be able to add/change records within a PKeyless table.

I saw this post and it works when I add records with composite keys:

[KeyBuilder does not contain a definition for HasForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649802/keybuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-hasforeignkey)

#### Table Structure (Composite Keys)

Region, User, Position

#### ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasKey(r=> new {r.User,r.Position,r.Region});
```

Basically, when an user inserts a record with a new region, the position after the newly input value will change.

(enter Position = 10, all int after 10 will increase by 1 like queueing)

When I edit records which involve the composite key (Position), it returns error `The property 'Record.Position' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.`.

Can I edit the records without actually adding a primary key into the table?

Comment: The primary key is necessary to identify exactly the row, so yes you need it, for table you want to edit

Comment: You can use, and need, the PK in the EF model to update any other property of `Record`. For incrementing `Position` you could use [`ExecuteUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant), but avoid using it for updating record that also updated by EF's change tracking (i.e. by PK).

Comment: As you see below, it's not clear what exactly is "keyless" here. The table? The EF entity as you'd prefer to have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is saying, You cannot directly UPDATE a property which is part of composite key... but you can always SEARCH it, REMOVE it and ADD a new entity with your changes: it's the same ;););)

P.S. The API Fluent **.HasKey(r=> new {r.User,r.Position,r.Region});** defines a COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the only way to achieve my desired result (update records with no PK field added). However, there might be performance issues with a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

So, why is it keyless when it has a composite key? By SQL definition a table needs a PK to identify rows uniquely. By your own statement, it has a (composite) key. So, the blazor app is in error to "pretend" is has no key.

Fix that - done.

You can not edit the table because any update would possibly hit multiple rows - that is how SL is defined, and the issue is totally your unwillingness to provide EF with the information you have.

Comment: It's the other way around. The db table is keyless, but the app pretends it's got a key. Of course that's perfectly possible (and it's not uncommon to see this in legacy systems) provided that the key is really unique. The fact that the "key" is modified all the time makes this a fragile proposition, but *technically* it's possible. Only EF blocks it, understandably.

Comment: So, the statement that the table has a composite key is a lie?

Comment: A lie is something deliberate :). From what I understand the database table doesn't have a primary key (as a database object) but does have 3 columns that are supposed to have unique combined values and, hence, EF can be told that it's the PK while in reality it isn't.

Comment: He says explicitly that the table structure has a composite key.